# Oracle Standby Database for Running Queries

Tags: oracle, database-administration

We have a physical standby database which is used only for running reports. It is not intended to be ever used as primary.

Now - a reporting database has much different requirements than an OLTP one.

I want to propose that we either convert this standby database from PHYSICAL to LOGICAL and create different database objects - especially INDEXES to support reporting.

What could be pros and cons of such approach ?

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance however I'm always looking to learn new concepts.  Is this what you are referring to: https://dataedo.com/blog/logical-vs-physical-data-dictionary

Comment: @CodeNovice - Oracle Data Guard is a tool from oracle. you can learn more about it from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41134/toc.htm